# Is it possible for certain library packages which have been packed for an ubuntu normal release to be installed into an ubuntu LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, lts

I am running the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I need certain packages as dependencies for an opensource project I want to contribute to, however the required package versions are only available for 20.10 normal release.

I realize that this isn't recommended but is there way to make apt remove that restriction and take them from the universe package registry into my ubuntu LTS?

Comment: You've not provided the packages, but unless they're very simple packages (like wallpapers), they'll pull in other dependencies making your *focal* system a *groovy* system, ie. your system won't be a LTS any longer.  This will depend on the packages; eg. wallpaper packages have no dependencies thus no real consequences.. but this isn't the case with most packages.

Comment: Assuming that the dependencies aren't for system packages, is there a way for apt to look for these versions as well @guiverc?

Comment: You can use `apt` commands (`apt-cache` etc), or just use packages.ubuntu.com to see dependencies... but each package can have it's own dependencies, thus others get *upgraded*, causing more to ....

Comment: Too broad. Which exactly package name?